# vb.net image download and populate on the picturebox error

Tags: c#, vb.net

i want to download image file from internet and open this image file into picturebox1 on the form.

i changed downloaded picture image name to cap.png

then i open this file onto picturebox1 but have problem in here.

always error like 'file is used by other process ' or 'out of memory'

whole day i try to make it work but i coudn't

if anyone help me much appreciate

```
            Dim client As New WebClient
            remBadstring = captchaMatch.Value.Replace("""", "")
            Dim myUrl = New Uri(remBadstring)
            client.DownloadFileAsync(myUrl, "cap.png")
            'My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(myUrl, Application.StartupPath & "/cap.png")              
            Dim img As Image
            Dim tmp As Image = Image.FromFile("cap.png")
            img = New Bitmap(tmp)
            tmp.Dispose()
            PictureBox1.Load(remBadstring) ' error hapen. 
            'PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("cap.png")
            Application.DoEvents()
            Dim myUrl2 As String = remBadstring
```

Comment: im very sorry bond i changed tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I don't have enough rep for comments, so I'll wrote here*

try to add after `client.DownloadFileAsync(myUrl, "cap.png")` add one more line `client.Dispose()`

Answer (score 0):

Use DownloadFile instead of DownloadFileAsync. Or, if you don't need a file, you can use the following:

```
    static Image DownloadImage(string address)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
            return Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(address)));
    }
```